# Python requests Module - Passing Nested XML as Query Parameters

Tags: python, xml, parameters, nested, python-requests

I'm trying to structure an HTTP PUT request using the Python `requests` module.  For all of my purposes thus far, I've been able to construct a dictionary with the XML element data that I'd like to send, which I then pass as query parameters.  My code looks like the following:

```
import requests

scan_params = {
    'type': 'T2 FSE 3D MICE'
    'quality': 'usable'
}
resp = requests.put(url, params=scan_params)
```

This works fine.  However, when I want to pass nested XML elements, or XML attributes, I'm not sure how to include these as parameters in scan_params.  What I'd like to do is something like:

```
import requests

scan_params = {
    'type': 'T2 FSE 3D MICE'
    'quality': 'usable',
    'parameters/te': 3.1
}
resp = requests.put(url, params=scan_params)
```

Where `te` is a child of `parameters`.  Likewise, I'm not sure how to specify attributes in this dictionary.

I want to avoid using some XML library to construct well-formed XML, since that will be an additional development step.

Any ideas for what I should be doing?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To code nested XML elements OR attributes as parameters in a query string, you can use a forward slash.

Example:

```
scan_params = {
    'type': 'T2 FSE 3D MICE'
    'quality': 'usable',
    'parameters/te': 3.1,
    'parameters/voxelRes/x': 1.0
}
```

where `te` is an element of `parameters`, and `x` is an attribute of `voxelRes`, which is itself an element of `parameters`.

I'm not sure what would happen if an element had an attribute AND an element with the same name, or whether that would even be considered well-formed XML.